# Flask API blocking OPTIONS requests

Tags: python, angularjs, flask, restful-architecture

I have an API written in Flask, when I am trying to use this API from AngularJS I am getting an 401 error unauthorized, same request with same credentials is working fine from Postman or HTTPie. This is happening with GET or POST request.

I noticed that the difference between HTTPie and Angular request is that Angular is calling OPTIONS before a GET request.

This is my python code where authentication is required(api is a blueprint):

```
@api.before_request
@rate_limit(limit=5, period=15)
@auth_token.login_required
def before_request():
   """All routes in this blueprint require authentication."""
   pass
```

The only method that is working from my api is one that is outside of this blueprint, my conclusion is that the @api.before_request and @auth_token.login_required are expecting credentials to be sent for the OPTIONS request, any idea what can I do?

Thank you very much

Comment: You sure this isn't a CORS issue?

Comment: I think is not, I have the CORS plugin for flask running. Chrome is showing this error "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:5000/api/v1/audios/. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401" . If I remove @auth_token.login_required from the before_request I can get the data(but without asking for login)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out the problem, I solved after updating the plugin Flask-HTTPAuth.

I was having the version 2.2.1 and after moving to 3.2.1 it solved.

Tried the same on an instance of Amazon EC2 and solved with the same solution so I am quite sure it was this.